# Javascript set first column style

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using javascript to modify a page's styling and it's working great. The next step however is to change the styling of the first column of a table. How can I identify and set the styling of the first column only? My other changes so far are based on ID or based on a number of items having a class. In this example I just know they are TH or TD elements, and I want to change the ones in the first column.

In case anyone asks, this is my code so far... this is working and doesn't include anything to do with setting the style of the first column

```
    function rotate_headers() {
    const collection = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) 
    {
    collection[i].innerHTML = 
    '<div style="padding-left: 100%;"><div style="transform: translate(7px, 3px)  rotate(315deg);  width: 30px;"><span style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  padding: 5px 10px; color:grey;"' + collection[i].innerHTML + '</span> </div></div>';
    // collection[i].style.background = "#6877c3"; //
    //collection[i].style.height = "100px"; //
    }
    
    const collection2 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-bordered");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection2.length; i++) 
    { collection2[i].style.border = "0px"; 
     collection2[i].style.marginTop = "95px";  
    }
    
    const collection3 = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection3.length; i++) 
    { collection3[i].classList.remove("highlight"); }
    
    const collection4 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-content");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection4.length; i++) 
    { collection4[i].style.padding = "1rem 1rem"; }
    
    const collection5 = document.getElementsByClassName("table-content");
    for (let i = 0; i < collection5.length; i++) 
    { collection5[i].style.width = "100px"; 
    collection5[i].style.position = "relative";
    collection5[i].style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    collection5[i].style.overflowX = "scroll"; 
    collection5[i].style.overflowY = "hidden"; 
    
     }
    
    }
```

The below code does what I want, but only if my table has an ID... which mine typically do not.

```
var table = document.getElementById('test');
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
        firstCol.style.background = 'red'; // or anything you want to do with first col
    }
```

The code below does not work... which is my problem

```
   var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
        firstCol.style.background = 'red'; // or anything you want to do with first col
    }
```

Comment: `tr th:first-child`, `tr td:first-child`

Comment: Thanks, how would I put that inline though?

`const collection6 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr td:first-child");`

Comment: `const collection6 = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `document.querySelectorAll('tr th:first-child, tr td:first-child')` then iterate the result setting the styles you want.

```js
let firstCol = document.querySelectorAll('tr th:first-child, tr td:first-child')
for (let i = 0; i < firstCol.length; i++) {
  firstCol[i].style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find answer in next article:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics

Styling without 
There is one last feature we'll tell you about in this article before we move on. HTML has a method of defining styling information for an entire column of data all in one place — the  and  elements. These exist because it can be a bit annoying and inefficient having to specify styling on columns — you generally have to specify your styling information on every  or  in the column, or use a complex selector such as :nth-child.

Comment: Thanks, sadly my problem is trying to do this via Javascript rather than just normal styling. My code adapts an existing page.